# Passing results of queries in promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using node-postgres for a database connection. For that I have APIs like that:

```
app.post('/api/insert', urlEncodedParser, function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
})
```

Now I need synchron steps:

1. Select specific id from table user
2. Check if id from table user already exists in table list
   3a) if id in table list does not exist, then insert data in table list
   3b) if id in table list exists, then update data in table list

So I have following code:

```
var userid = 0;
var listEntry = 0;

client
.query('SELECT "ID" FROM "User" WHERE "PW" = $1 AND "Name" = $2', [req.body.pw, req.body.name])
.then(res => userid = res.rows[0])
.catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
.query('SELECT " FROM "List" WHERE "UserID" = $1', [userid])
.then(res => listEntry = res.rows[0])
.catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
.query('INSERT INTO "List" ("UserID", "LastDate")', [userid, req.body.date])
.then(res => userid = res.rows[0])
.catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
.query('UPDATE "List" SET "LastDate" = $1', [req.body.date])
.then(res => userid = res.rows[0])
.catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
.finally(() { client.end()
});
```

What do I need to change that I can have this synchron steps as listed above? Sorry, I am new to javascript and node-postgres.

Comment: A promise does not have a `.query` method. You should write `; client.query(…`. Or maybe `.then(() => client.query(…))` if you want sequential execution.

Comment: Can you use `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks four your answer. But how can I jump over a then, if I don't need this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you return in one then ends up in the following then. For example:

```js
client.query("SELECT...")
    .then((result) => {
        // do something with the result
        return 42;
    })
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
```

The first log prints 42 because the previous `then` returned 42 and the second prints `undefined` because the previous `then` returned nothing = `undefined`. So you actually want something like this:

```js
client.query('SELECT "ID" FROM "User" WHERE "PW" = $1 AND "Name" = $2', [req.body.pw, req.body.name])
    .then((res) => {
        const userid = res.rows[0];
        return client.query('SELECT " FROM "List" WHERE "UserID" = $1', [userid]).then(() => {
            return client.query('INSERT INTO "List" ("UserID", "LastDate")', [userid, req.body.date]);
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        return client.query('UPDATE "List" SET "LastDate" = $1', [req.body.date])
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => client.end());
```

This was you don't even need the semi-global variables `userid` and `listEntry`. This is generally a good thing.

The code can be more simplified when using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

If you don't want to execute the following queries because there are no rows in the first response you can do something like this:

```js
client.query('SELECT "ID" FROM "User" WHERE "PW" = $1 AND "Name" = $2', [req.body.pw, req.body.name])
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.rows.length > 0) {
            const userid = res.rows[0];
            return client.query('SELECT " FROM "List" WHERE "UserID" = $1', [userid]).then(() => {
                return client.query('INSERT INTO "List" ("UserID", "LastDate")', [userid, req.body.date]);
            }).then(() => {
                return client.query('UPDATE "List" SET "LastDate" = $1', [req.body.date])
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => client.end());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that. So far I understood, the second 'then(()' will just be executed if the first 'then((res)' is not being executed. Is that correct?
The problem I have right now is that the first 'then((res)' will be executed even if there is no result doing the select query.

Comment: The callback in `then` will be executed unless the previous `then` returns a rejected promise. It's like regular statements and exceptions: the next statement will always be executed unless the previous statement throws an error. If you don't want to execute the following queries because the first response returned no rows you can do something like this [see my post, I edited it].